# DbContext: Lazy Loading when assigning null to a navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, lazy-loading, dbcontext

I have a very basic example C# program which uses EF6 with DbContext and which contains two classes:

```
MyTable1   1...n   MyTable2
```

I have the following code:

```
// Creation of instances and saving them to the database.
using (var context = new EFTestEntities()) {
  var myTable1 = new MyTable1() { ID = 1 };
  var myTable2 = new MyTable2() { ID = 2 };
  myTable1.MyTable2.Add(myTable2);
  context.MyTable1.Add(myTable1);
  context.SaveChanges();
}

// This part here is what my question is about.
using (var context = new EFTestEntities()) {
  var myTable2 = context.MyTable2.Where(e => e.ID == 2).FirstOrDefault(); // First line
  myTable2.MyTable1 = null; // Second line
  var myTable1AssignedToMyTable2 = myTable2.MyTable1.ID; // Value '1'; third line
}
```

The second part of the code is where my question is about.

`myTable1AssignedToMyTable2` will have the value '1'. I would expect a `NullReferenceException`.

When starting SQL Server Profiler to see all database accesses I realized that the MyTable1 navigation property of myTable2 is due to lazy loading automatically loaded when it is first accessed. This happens in the third line or when hovering the word `MyTable1` in the second line in a debug session.
After the lazy loading took place it can be set to null.

But: If I replace the null assignment above with:

```
 myTable2.MyTable1 = new MyTable1() { ID = 11 };
```

Then `myTable1AssignedToMyTable2` will have the expected value '11'. And no further database accesses take place.

Further Observation:

If I first assign a new value and assign then the old value again it is still ignored. Only when I call `DetectChanges()` in between the behavior is as expected. Example:

```
using (var context = new EFTestEntities()) {
  var myTable2 = context.MyTable2.Where(e => e.ID == 2).FirstOrDefault();
  myTable2.MyTable1 = new MyTable1() { ID = 11 };
  // context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
  myTable2.MyTable1 = null;
  var myTable1AssignedToMyTable2 = myTable2.MyTable1.ID; // Value is still '1'
}
```

Conclusions:

- Assigning the current value again seems to be ignored by EF. Further tests showed that it doesn't matter whether it is `null` or not.
- Sometimes a `DetectChanges()` is needed for EF to realise that something has changed, sometimes not. Replacing the null assignment by an assignment with a new object (see above, at the middle of this post) doesn't need a `DetectChanges()` call. But doing exactly this again and setting it back to null needs a `DetectChanges()` call (see example right above).

Is this correct? It is not very intuitive in my opinion. Assigning null is ignored, assigning a not null value is not ignored.

Comment: Yeah, that's not a great experience, but for me it's yet another reason why lazy loading should be avoided.

Comment: Unrelated to the question but @telandor, you can pass a filter function to `FirstOrDefault` or you can actually use [DbSet<TEntity>.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbset-1.find?view=entity-framework-6.2.0)

Comment: Hi Marie. Thank you for your reply. Instead of using the Where() call you mean? What would be the benefit in this example?